# Parse docblocks of function calls, not function definitions?

Tags: php, regex, comments, docblocks

I'm trying to get docblocks preceding certain function calls in a PHP file. The difference to the usual approach is that I'm not trying to parse docblocks of function definitions.

Example file:

```
<?php
$data = get_data($id);

if ( empty( $data->random ) ) {
  /**
  * Brief description
  *
  * @since 1.0
  * @param int $var Variable
  */
  do_function( 'identifier', $var );
  exit;
}

// random comment
$status = get_random_function($post);
?>
```

`do_function` does appear on various places in various files I'm going to parse. What I'm trying to get and parse is the preceding docblock including the function call.

A Reflection class is not an option as the files don't include classes, so I'm stuck with the following RegExp which returns an empty array:

```
preg_match_all('/(\/\*.+\*\/)[\s]{0,}do_function/m', $filecontent_as_string, $results);
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Use something like [an annotation parser](https://github.com/mindplay-dk/php-annotations) to parse the annotations?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) or [Reflection](https://www.php.net/language.oop5.reflection) for this case. You may also see [file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) in which you could use to match those certain lines of comments and have it return an array of lines.

If you desire a regular expression in this case, this should do what you want.

```
/(\/\*(?:[^*]|\n|(?:\*(?:[^\/]|\n)))*\*\/)\s+do_function/
```

See a demo in action [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/hW4qQ6)

Regular expression:

```
(                     group and capture to \1:
 \/                   match '/'
 \*                   match '*'
 (?:                  group, but do not capture (0 or more times)
   [^*]   |           any character except: '*' OR
   \n     |           any character of: '\n' (newline) OR
   (?:                group, but do not capture:
     \*               match '*'
     (?:              group, but do not capture:
       [^\/] |        any character except: '/' OR
       \n             any character of: '\n' (newline)
     )                end of grouping
   )                  end of grouping
  )*                  end of grouping
  \*                  match '*'
   \/                 match '/'
)                     end of \1
 \s+                  whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
 do_function          'do_function'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a much simpler regex with the following:

```
#(?s)(/\*(?:(?!\*/).)+\*/)\s+do_function#
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/iH1mJ5)

`(?s)` can be set as flag (`#(/\*(?:(?!\*/).)+\*/)\s+do_function#s`) and makes the `.` match newlines.

`/\*` matches the beginning of the docblock.

`(?:(?!\*/).)+` matches every character except `*/`.

`\*/` matches the end of the docblock.

`\s+do_function` matches spaces and newlines until the `do_function` is found.

Comment: I almost used a negative look ahead. ;)

Comment: @hwnd Yea, it's a little trick I learned while browsing SO =P Yours works just fine otherwise ^^